# Inner Exception in outer Join

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I don't know why my programme doesn't work. Could you help me please ! I have a inner Exception when i run it.

```
  var peoples = new List<People>();
   peoples.Add(new People { Model = "Mustang", FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "L'indien" });
   peoples.Add(new People { Model = "Corvet", FirstName = "Luc", LastName = "Emince" });
   peoples.Add(new People { Model = "Verron", FirstName = "pierre", LastName = "Uneed" });
   peoples.Add(new People { Model = "Viper", FirstName = "Martial", LastName = "Roste" });
   peoples.Add(new People { Model = "Camaro", FirstName = "Franck", LastName = "Vador" });

   var cars =  this._cars = new List<Car>();
   cars.Add(new Car { Model = "Mustang", Description = "Gros paté" });
   cars.Add(new Car { Model = "Mustang", Description = "Paté" });
   cars.Add(new Car { Model = "Verron", Description = "Très gros paté" });
   cars.Add(new Car { Model = "Viper", Description = "Attention paté" });
   cars.Add(new Car { Model = "Viper", Description = "Attention paté" });

    var PeopleCar = from people in peoples
                     join car in cars on people.Model equals car.Model into outer
                     from car in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                           people.FirstName,
                           people.LastName,                                 
                           car.Model,
                           Desc = (people == null) ? "CASSE DE MERDE" : car.Description
                      };

  foreach (var item in PeopleCar)
  {
         textBox1.AppendText(String.Format("Mr {0} {1} a une voiture model {2} qui envoie du {3}"
                + Environment.NewLine, item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Model, item.Desc));
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you give us the exception text?  Which exception is it?

Comment: Not the text - the full exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your select define field names:

```
               select new
               {
                  FirstName = people.FirstName,
                  LastName = people.LastName,
                  Model = car.Model,
                  Desc = (people == null) ? "CASSE DE MERDE" : car.Description
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing an outer join, `car` can be `null` - you should guard against it in the `select`:

```
           select new
           {
              FirstName = people.FirstName,
              LastName = people.LastName,
              Model = car == null ? null ; car.Model,
              Desc = car == null ? null : car.Description
            };
```

Also, you didn't ask but you could use collection initializer syntax:

```
var peoples = new List<People>()
{
    new People { Model = "Mustang", FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "L'indien" }),
    new People { Model = "Corvet", FirstName = "Luc", LastName = "Emince" }),
    new People { Model = "Verron", FirstName = "pierre", LastName = "Uneed" }),
    ...
};
```

Comment: The null protection for `people` is either incomplete or pointless.